# Display qtip2 bubble on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm using Qtip2 to display the return of an ajax request. I want to display it, only when the user click on it. So I saw the `show: 'click',hide: 'click'` attributes but it doesn't work.

I tried with something simple, without the ajax request, but it still doesn't work.It is displayed on hover.

```
$('#test').qtip({
       content:{
           show: 'click',
           hide: 'click',
           text : "test"
       }
    });
```

Do you know why this doesn't work ? And if there is an other way to do it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation shows the following style of using the code:

```
$('#test').qtip({
       content:{
           text : "test"
       },
       show: 'click',
       hide: 'click'
    });
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/qTip2/x0ocvp52/

Try this and let us know if this works.

Comment: Ok, it's outside the content, I missed it ! It works now ! Thanks a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The `show` and `hide` properties are outside the `content`. So try this:

```
$('#test').qtip({
  content: {
    text: 'test'
  },
  show: 'click',
  hide: 'click'
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lulylulu/s21q2y82/)